# How to calculate FPM as related to Residential HVAC air handler

Tags: hvac, air-conditioning

I'm working with the formula that `CFM = FPM X Cross sectional Area` and I'm trying to calculate an accurate FPM through my air filter in my air handler.

Originally, I was simply using the cross sectional area of the filter opening, 20x20 (19.5 x 19.5 actual) which is about 2.6 sq ft. My air handler is pushing 1098 CMF, and so I have:

```
1098 CFM / 2.6 sq ft =  422 FPM
```

Which I believe is accurate, if the opening were just a gaping hole instead of an actual filter. The trouble comes when I referenced this number `422 FPM` and someone said I should actually be using the total square footage of the pleated media in the filter, through which the air is passing. In my 1" filter thats 5.55 sq ft, and in my 2" filter thats 12 sq ft. That would yield the following calculations:

```
1098 CFM / 5.55 sq ft =  197 FPM
1098 CFM / 12 sq ft =  91 FPM
```

What I'm ultimately trying to do is determine an accurate FPM calculation, so that I can compare that value to data sheets on various filters. The data sheets I have, have tables and graphs where the X axis is FPM and the Y axis is Pressure Drop. Thus, if I can get an accurate FPM calculation, I can see the estimated pressure drop at various sizes of filter, and at various CFM settings on my air handler.

Should I therefore be using total filter media as the `sq ft` variable, or just the cross sectional area of the opening, or something entirely different?

Comment: There is some industry formula or rule of thumb(s) that someone else here will likely know and comment on but, you could just directly test the air flow on the downside of the filter. Here is a random one that was first to come up on a search, just for an example https://www.amazon.com/Anemometer-Temperature-Thermometer-Windsurfing-Kitesurfing/dp/B07X7WMCSP/ref=psdc_13825011_t1_B07FPWMSDF

Comment: I agree, and I'm probably going to order one. I was hoping to be able to calculate it on paper, even with some margin of error, so that I could predict the pressure drop, without having to actually change the CFM on my air handler, and just by using the data sheets so I didn't have to buy different filters to test. Thank you for the link!

Comment: I know very little directly about the subject especially general practice, but filters generally will have less airflow for an increase in filtering ability. Because HVAC are designed systems, I would expect that the filters have an efficiency rating. A quick search turned up Minimum Efficiency Reporting Value (MERV) if that helps at all until someone shows up that can provide you with a more direct answer

Answer (score 1):

Your method of FPM X cross sectional area won’t come out right for a large trunk line, the problem is the airflow is faster in the middle and slower at the edges so usually a grid of measurements are taken and an average flow is created. I have a book that gives the recommended number of points based on the size of memory serves 3 points 2 on the sides and one in the middle averaged gets close with the big book. Measurements were not supposed to be taken the width of the opening from a turn, that’s silly because most openings are at a 90 to the duct within an inch or so. I just take the measurements wherever and it has always been close enough for residential.

Answer (score 0):

The original question asked is one that I've also been looking at.  From what I can gather, it appears that when filter manufacturers list initial pressure drop for a new filter at a given flow velocity (FPM), the velocity referenced is (average flow) through the duct/filter cross sectional area, not through the area you could measure if you unfolded the pleated media.  At least there are some other graphs of air flow (CFM) vs pressure drop that seem to indicate this, although I've not found all of the above in one place.   If someone can definitively confirm that would help.